# How can I set up a JDBC connection to an OpenOffice Database odb file?

Tags: jdbc, openoffice.org

For instructional purposes, I want to set up a database in a Linux environment, then conenct to it using JDBC.  OpenOffice looks a lot simpler thatn MySQL, but I'm not sure how to get the connection to it set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.odb` files are zipped HSQL files. [Here's a guide](http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/01/java-and-openoffice-base-db-through.html) on how to handle them via Java.